# Using templateURL to load from an external resource in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework, angularjs, directive

I am creating a custom directive in AngularJS that takes advantage of the templateUrl key. The problem I'm running in to is that we are hosting these template files on an external CDN, so I am getting an Access-Control-Allow-Origin error.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://path_to_cdn/template_file.html. Origin http://xx.xx.xx.xx is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I read somewhere that I could do something like this...

```
<script type="text/ng-template" src="http://path_to_cdn/template_file.html"></script>
```

...but this is not really ideal and I couldn't get it to work properly anyway.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is server side. This is one way to solve it

Assuming you have access to both the servers, you do this:

First the terminologies

Domain 1: The domain which loads the javascript that makes the templateURL request

Domain 2: The domain from which you are trying to get template from

You have to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin option in the ***response*** header of Domain 2. The value of it should be the url of the Domain 1.

Comment: Is there another way to do this (I would have to submit a request to the server people and wait until they get around to it) - possibly with .htaccess perhaps? I do have FTP access.

Comment: The problem is most browsers do not allow such requests to be made. Some stupid security issue. 
this might help: http://usejquery.com/posts/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide, though I personally think talking to your CDN team is the best option.

Comment: If you can't get the CDN to send the correct headers, you can add a reverse proxy in your server to inject the headers yourself.

Comment: Guillaume86, can you point me in a direction where I might learn how to do that?